# Data type input to tflite model does not match

Tags: android, tensorflow, kotlin

I made the following SimpleRNN model with python.

```
python
#Omit
Xtest = np.zeros((1, 10, 1102))
#Omit
pred = model.predict(Xtest, verbose=0)[0]
```

As you can see, I used a three-dimensional array of integer as input for model.

Then, I ported this model for android as `.tflite`. 
In the code below, the part called tfliteModel corresponds.

```
kotlin
Interpreter(tfliteModel!!).use { interpreter ->
    val input_onehot = Array(1) { Array(10) {Array<Int>(1102) {0} } }
    val output = Array(1) {Array<Float>(1102) { 0F } }
    //some operation like　making it a one hot vector
    interpreter.run(input_onehot, output)
}
```

But Android studio threw an error like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataType error: cannot resolve DataType of [[[Ljava.lang.Integer;
```

Why does this error occur?
How can I load my integer array into my model?

I used [this site](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/android#build_in_android_studio_with_tensorflow_lite_aar_from_jcenter) as a reference. 
But, this was referring to the image and not the NLP・・・

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why, but I solved it by reading as float instead of int.
I used np.int32・・・
Perhaps numpy's int32 and kotlin's Int32 may not be compatible.